# Why wont IMAP in Python read emails consistently the same way? It reads it with html tags and without/ not the same always

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, imap

Alright, this is a pretty weird problem. So I have a program, it works as so:

1. User sends a song name in an email to -------@gmail.com
2. When -------@gmail.com reads the email (IMAP) it searches up the song on genius (Selenium)
3. --------@gmail.com sends back cool info/lyrics about the song to the original user.

My problem is at step 2; When the email is read, it sometimes will be in the string like, "The World is Yours", and other times it will be, [image: enter image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKEYt.pngdescription here] format. Sometimes it has html tags sometimes it doesnt. I have code to manipulate the string when it has html tags to be raw, but then it messes it up when it randomly goes to raw format. I used some code I found online and modified it since Im not the best with IMAP but heres the part of my program that finds the song name of the most recent email sent to it.

```
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    # authenticate
    imap.login(username, password)

    status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
    # number of top emails to fetch
    N = 1
    # total number of emails
    messages = int(messages[0])

    for i in range(messages, messages-N, -1):
        # fetch the email message by ID
        res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
        for response in msg:
            if isinstance(response, tuple):
                # parse a bytes email into a message object
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
                # decode the email subject
                subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
                if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                    # if it's a bytes, decode to str
                    subject = subject.decode(encoding)
                # decode email sender
                From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
                if isinstance(From, bytes):
                    From = From.decode(encoding)
                print("Subject:", subject)
                print("From:", From)
                # if the email message is multipart
                if msg.is_multipart():
                    # iterate over email parts
                    for part in msg.walk():
                        # extract content type of email
                        content_type = part.get_content_type()
                        content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                        try:
                            # get the email body
                            body = part.get_payload()#(decode=True).decode()
                        except:
                            pass
                        if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                            # print text/plain emails and skip attachments
                            print(body)
                        else:
                            pass
                else:
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                    # get the email body
                    body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    if content_type == "text/plain":
                        # print only text email parts
                        print(body)
    # close the connection and logout
    imap.close()
    imap.logout()
```

**body IS THE VARIABLE USED FOR THE SONGNAME**
Any help is appreciated and also if there is a much easier way to just grab the most recent email feel free to tell me.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your headline into a question? The community isn't able to easily to help you with a statement of something being broken.

Comment: I would also recommend wrapping the way you interact with the message in an object for easier debugging.

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: At a guess, some people send you HTML mail and some people send you plain text.

Comment: At a guess, some people send you HTML mail and some people send you plain text.